# Website is displayed as HTML-Code instead of rendered HTML - indeterministic

Tags: html, http, servlets, web, rendering

I have a problem with a website, where sometimes only the HTML text is displayed in the browser window, instead of the rendered HTML page. This happens sometimes in all browsers.
Example URL:
http://www.starkl.at/view/p-1258/Newsletter---Gartentipp/

The HTTP request headers from IE9 are (Cookies are not shown):

```
GET http://www.starkl.at/view/p-1258/Newsletter---Gartentipp/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://www.starkl.at/view/p-1931/Service/
Accept-Language: de-AT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: www.starkl.at
Pragma: no-cache
```

The HTTP response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 07:43:49 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 21160
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Also the content length (in bytes) seems to match.
It's a Java 6/7 application running on a Tomcat 6/7, with an additional httpd 2.2.x in front.

Any idea what the problem could be????

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem was an out-of-date httpd version :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser writes the code and not renders it is because it's being told to do so, probably your app is returning html encoded in a way that browser thinks it's plain text.

Comment: The HTML code starts with "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xml:lang="de" lang="de" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">" and is correctly terminated with "</html>"

Can you please be a bit more specific what you mean. This is exactly what the content-type text/html says.

Comment: Without knowing your code is difficult to say. But probably you are returning to your clients html as a string in some places, and maybe you are specifying in some place that this string should be treated literally. This would make your browser to write it down instead of trying to parse and render it. But I'm just guessing, as you haven't provided us any code to check...

Comment: Well the code is too complex to show here. In short it is: 1. Build HTML in memory. 2. Serialize to one big String. 3. Convert to UTF-8 encoded byte array. 4. Write byte array at once to HttpServletResponse and set the content-length according to the byte array length

Comment: I bet the problem is in the encoding. Probably "<" ">" characters are arriving encoded to the client and thus the browser just writes them, being unable to render the HTML code.

Comment: No, that it is definitively not the problem, as it works most of the time. Please look at the page and see yourself. My thought currently go more into the direction of the used httpd/tomcat versions... I'm 99,99% sure that we're emitting everything correctly! But thanks anyway for your guesses!

Comment: The problem was an old httpd version 2.2.3 on CentOS 5. By upgrading to httpd 2.2.22 the problem was solved!

Answer (score -5):

Open tools, options, email, email options, then uncheck "Read all standard mail in plain text." This is for Outlook 2003 so your version, if not 2003, might be slightly different.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Outlook or email.